# how to construct a class for complex number in python?

Tags: python, class, methods, data-structures, complex-numbers

First, I know there is data structure for complex number in scipy. I'm just following a computational physics textbook, and this is one of the questions.
So far this is what I've got:

```
class complex:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.re=x
        self.im=y
    def __add__(self, other):
        return complex(self.re+other.re, self.im+other.im)
    def __sub__(self, other):
        return complex(self.re-other.re, self.im-other.im)        
    def __mul__(self, other):
        return complex(self.re*other.re - self.im*other.im, 
        self.re*other.im + self.im*other.re)        
    def __repr__(self):
        return '(%f , %f)' %(self.re, self.im)
```

but how should I implement division, complex conjugate, modulus and phase in the class I have created?

thanks

Comment: Do you know mathematically how to perform those operations with complex numbers? If so, where are you stuck with regards to implementing it in Python? If your question is how to perform those operations, that is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I have no problems working with complex numbers. I just don't know how to implement them in python.

Comment: You already found the basic arithmetic special methods; do you mean you want to know how to hook into the division and modulus operators too? It isn't clear from your question what exactly you are struggling with here.

Comment: It does not answer your question, but note that you don't need Scipy for complex numbers, they are a built-in type in Python. https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#imaginary-literals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Division you should implement with `__div__` and modulus with `__abs__`. Complex conjugate and phase you'll have to choose your own method names for. For example,

```
def conj(self):
    return complex(self.re, - self.im)
```

(to be called with `z.conj()`). Note that you won't be able to define new Python syntax for your class: you can't make `z*` work, for example. You should also define right-multiplication with `__rmul__`, and `__pow__` if you feel like it. And don't forget unary minus, `__neg__`. But not all of the other double-underscored operator methods make sense to implement with complex numbers. There's [a list in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html).

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your initial suggestions of `__div__` and `__abs__`. I'd suggest `__truediv__` for division (and maybe also `__floordiv__` if you want to support the `//` division operator), and `__mod__` for modulus. `__truediv__` is required to implement division in Python 3, and a good idea in Python 2 as well (use with `from __future__ import division`). For the complex conjugate, it might make sense to reuse the unary `~` operator, which returns the bitwise inverse for integers. It can be implemented in a custom class by defining an `__inverse__` method.

Comment: I agree with `__truediv__` for completeness. But `__mod__` implements the `%` infix for modulo arithmetic: this and floor division surely have no meaning for the complex numbers. Reusing `~` for the complex conjugate would work, though.